# Seeking Wisdom on Automated Integration Testing Through all Environments, from Local Dev to Production

Tags: helix, unit-testing, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I want to run tests in all of My Environments, that are not unit tests but Integration tests to confirm

Well in this case that Security is setup correctly on all items and that the users we in Roles we have designed can do all of the things...

Insert an item into a Site...
Add a Rendering...
View a node in the Content Tree...

All of these sorts of things need to Run in the actual Sitecore Context

I want to run these tests, build them, in C# and then install them into the webroot as I go up the environments and then run them in such a way that I can capture the effect in a Circle CI workflow (CI/CD) and see what is up

And also run them from my local Development Environment (from my build.ps1 script)

Had anybody done this, or does anybody have any examples or suggestions...

We are in containers so theoretically I should be able to do this in a docker file or something the way the build is done

Any experience anybody has had testing Sitecore, integration testing in the actual Sitecore context, please share as I am just not sure how to proceed here...

Thanks
Baxter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have not gone into the full editing experience, but we use APIs with security tokens to do work in Sitecore. Then use Ghost inspector to analyze the work. Whether it is a visual pixel by pixel screenshot evaluation or an json API where we interrogate the response. Finally we delete the changes and report any errors.